# [iPhone]the same picture used in different view seems to be not the same

Tags: iphone

i use a picture in two view in my app, the first is in the splash screen and the second in the main view, it's the same picture, same dimensions, the difference is that one called Default.png (splashscreen) and the second called background.png(for the main view), also background.png is changed in opacity but i insist that the dimensions are the same, so when i run the app, it seems not identical, ca you help me please, thx in advance :)

**background.png:**

[image]

**Default.png:**

[image]

Comment: i would like to mention that the red part is not the same :)

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image? I suspect they are 320x480. Try making them 320x460. This way you exclude the status bar. I think with the Default.png, the statusbar overlaps, while the image is resized in the background.png

Comment: i did like you said so change it both to 320*460 but the same prblem still appear :(

Comment: Could you upload the full image somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you taking into account the status bar? The difference in the two pictures looks like 20px. Try to se the y origin to -20 in the background.png, (or just crop the png by 20px).